# Replacing tire schrader core without deflating

Tags: tires, schrader-valve

If I am using a schrader core removal tool to replace the suspected leaky tire schrader, should I try to position the valve to be at 12 o'clock so that it can come out easily and that you can support the new core using gravity? What happens if the tool loses the grip of the core while it's inside the tool?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to remove and replace the Schrader valve core without deflating the tire. Put the stem in whatever clocked position is most comfortable for you to insert the new core. I'm right handed, so I'd probably put the stem at 9 o'clock so the stem would be facing my right hand. Use both hands to insert the new core, because the tool WILL NOT support the new core by itself. Use one hand on the tool and one hand to guide the core, guiding the core up into the stem, then turn the tool to tighten the new core in place. Air will be coming out of the tire as you are replacing the core, so refill the tire up to pressure after replacing the core.

Comment: ok but what if the core fell of the tip of the rod pushing it inside while it's in the middle of the tool?

Comment: The tool should be slotted. You don't use the tool to hold it. You use the tool to twist it AFTER it is in the stem. There is no way the tool CAN hold it. Hold the core with your fingers and stick it in the stem. Then use the tool to keep it in the hole while you twist it to screw the core in. If that's not what you're doing, you're doing it wrong.

Comment: But It is inside the tool shaft, I cannot hold it. I added a picture. it is not a screwdriver style one

Comment: I'm pretty sure what you are showing in the picture is not a tool for tires, but for use on AC systems. It doesn't fit on a tire stem. [Here is one for a tire.](https://mobileimages.lowes.com/productimages/2ee34705-9a4e-45be-8c33-2d67fc7e7d43/14224340.jpg)

Comment: that tool you linked could not do while the tire is (remains) inflated

Comment: If you follow my directions YES IT CAN.